# hfe classifications in data sheets

Tags: transistors, datasheet

This is a snippet of the data sheet of the BJT transistor 2SC828A.
[image]

1. What do they mean by Q R and S classifications?
2. I know that 2 in the code means transistor. What do the other numbers and letters mean (SC828A)?

Link to the data sheet:

[2SC828A data sheet](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/108448/ETC/2SC828A.html)

Comment: People will be more likely to give you an answer if you give us a link to the full datasheet.

Comment: The BC548 is a BJT and it doesn't have the front 2. But the 2N2222 is a BJT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [...] BJT transistor 2SC828A
>
> 1. What do they mean by Q R and S classifications?

These are the different ranges of \$h_{FE}\$ values, as shown in your original question, which each of those transistors could have. Look on the transistor for one of the letters Q, R or S often marked just underneath an abbreviated part number like 828A.

If the transistor has no such letter Q, R or S marking (sometimes called a Current Gain Group) then all you know (without measurement) is that its \$h_{FE}\$ value should be within the limits shown on the datasheet. Your linked datasheet shows the \$h_{FE}\$ minimum = 130 and maximum = 520:

[image: hfe minimum and maximum from original datasheet]

As expected, those values fit with the lower and upper limits of those classifications/groups.

> 2. I know that 2 in the code means transistor. What do the other numbers and letters mean (SC828A)?

This is the [JIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIS_semiconductor_designation) marking standard. In the case of the 2SC828A, they mean:

- SC = NPN HF bipolar transistor
- 828 = the JEITA-EDEREC number assigned to this type of transistor originally; the individual digits have no additional meaning
- A = a later version than the original (i.e. the one without any letter suffix); multiple versions are possible for some devices e.g. B, C suffixes etc.

  The *general* rule is that you can safely replace an earlier suffix letter device, with a later one (e.g. you can replace a 2SC828 with a 2SC828A) but not vice versa.

  (Same thing applies with the 2N2222 and 2N2222A, for example, where the 2N2222A has some improved maximum voltage ratings. However the meaning of a suffix can vary; if in doubt, find better datasheets for that device which explains them.)

For *this particular transistor*, the "A" suffix versions have some improved voltage ratings, as shown in [this datasheet](http://files.rct.ru/pdf/transistor/2sc828.pdf) which covers both the 2SC828 and 2SC828A. The differences are summarised as:

[image: differences between 2SC828 and 2SC828A from datasheet]

Answer (score 3):

Let's dissect the word `2SC828A`...

> 2

This is part of the Japanese Industrial Standard where they denote the markings of transistors with 2SC, 2SA and more. The "2" like you said means it's a transistor (where "1" means diode).

---

> SC

Again part of the JIS, the "SC" stands for NPN high frequency transistor.

---

> 828

So far I am unable to tell a pattern between the 3 numbers and the other characteristics. All I know is that if the number is different from another 2SC transistor, some characteristics would vary.

---

> A

The A in 2SC828A denotes the voltage rating of the transistor. Generally, higher values like B and C have higher voltage ratings. Like the TIP35C.

---

**But wait...** There is an extra letter that will show up on your transistor. So your transistor will actually say something like, 2SC828AQ, 2SC828AR or 2SC828AS, being 3 variants of 2SC828A. This explains your question with the Q/R/S part of the hFE shown in your datasheet.

The suffix your transistor has determines which hFE gain it will have, as concluded from the datasheet.

- `Q` in `2SC828AQ` has a hFE of 130-260.
- `R` in `2SC828AR` has a hFE of 180-360.
- `S` in `2SC828AS` has a hFE of 260-520.

These suffix letters are also Hfe ranks. See [here](http://engineering.rohmsemiconductor.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1/1/what-is-the-transistor-hfe-ranking).

---

Source: http://www.transparentsound.com/transistors/vintage-transistors/JIS/jis01.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this link for an explanation of the hFE ranking.

http://engineering.rohmsemiconductor.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1/1/what-is-the-transistor-hfe-ranking

In case the link does not work anymore! Here some further information.
The ranking code is mentioned as a suffix after the basic partnumber.
hFE Ranking Codes
hFE Range
A 16 - 32
B 25 - 50
D 60 - 120
E 100 - 200
F 160 - 320
M 39 - 82
N 56 - 120
P 82 - 180
Q 120 - 270
R 180 - 390
S 270 - 560
E 390 - 820
U 560 - 1200
V 820 - 1800
W 1200 - 2700
The complete number would be 2SC828A (suffix R,Q,S)
The suffix A indicating the voltage range.

Comment: Please summarize the relevant information so that your answer will still be useful if the linked document changes or is removed.